# Why can I not use substring in this situation?

Tags: java, string, api, substring

I'm trying to separate the words in a sentence. Each word of the sentence is stored into the string `word`, and then it adds everything back into one string again.

But why do I get an error with the substring line?

```
        String sent = IO.readString();
        char x;
        String word ="";
        int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sent.length(); i++){
        x = sent.charAt(i);
            if(x == ' ')
           {
            word = sent.substring(x-count,x);
            word = word + ' ';
            count =0;
           }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Is it a secret error?  Or are you allowed to share it with us so that we can help you?  Error messages usually contain helpful information--don't hide it from us.

Comment: What error are you getting, and with what inputs (ie, what value of `sent`)? What are you expecting to see? The more you give us, the easier it'll be for us to answer. In fact, the more you give us, the more likely it is that you'll find the solution yourself (which is a useful skill to build).

Answer (score 3):

`word = sent.substring(x-count,x);` should be `word = sent.substring(i-count,i);`

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` is a `char`, not an `int`, here

```
word = sent.substring(x-count,x);
```

and it should (probably) be something like

```
word = sent.substring(i-count,i);
```

because `i` is the position in the `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `String.split()`, which returns a `String` array.

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

To use spaces and punctuation as a separator, you could do something like this:

```
String[] arrWords = sentence.split("([ ,.]+)");
```

If you really want to go with your original route, you'll have to add some special cases for the first word and last word.  Although, what happens when there are multiple spaces, or punctuation?  Test it and find out!

```
public class SeparateWords
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String sent ="Hello there how are you";
    char x;
    String word ="";
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= sent.length(); i++){
       if (i == sent.length()){
         word = sent.substring(i-count+1,i);
         System.out.println(word);
         break;
       }
        x = sent.charAt(i);

        if(x == ' ')
        {
          if ((i-count) == 0){
            word = sent.substring(i-count,i);
          }
          else{
            word = sent.substring(i-count+1,i);
          }
          System.out.println(word);
          word = word + ' ';

          count =0;
        }
        count++;
    }

  }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
there
how
are
you
```

Comment: True, and an example of why you should *not* go this route and instead use existing, well-tested utility classes like [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Thanks for the String.split() tip! and thanks for explaining the rest.